# DOM add checkbox with div in list javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working form that add's new list items to a list. But my items should be checkboxes inside a DIV. Is there a way to achieve this?

```js
$("#addcheckbox").click(function() {
  var z = document.getElementById('newcheckbox').value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(z));
  entry.className = 'list-group-item';
  $("ul#groceries").append(entry);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" id="groceries">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Bread
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Apples
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, then *use* jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use append only:

```
$("#addcheckbox").click(function() {
  $("#groceries").append('<li class="list-group-item"><div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"> Bread</div></li>');
});
```

append argument may be any html in quotes

another example:

```js
var arr= ['bread', 'apples', 'eggs'];
var i = 0;
$("#addcheckbox").click(function() {
    $("#groceries").append('<li class="list-group-item"><div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">' + arr[i] + '</div></li>');
    i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addcheckbox">Add checkbox</button>
<p>List:</p>
<ul id="groceries"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the jQuery functions to create the elements to insert and append them to your list. If there is dynamic content in your entry, use jQuery's text() to prevent encoding issues.

```js
$("#addcheckbox").on("click", function() {
  var $entry = $('<li class="list-group-item"><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> <span></span></label></div></li>');
  $entry.find("label span").text($('#newcheckbox').val());
  $("ul#groceries").append($entry);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" id="groceries">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Bread
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Apples
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="newcheckbox" value="New Checkbox"><button id="addcheckbox">Add</button>
```